# TRIGGER AFTER INSERT duplicate UserId

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I added on the ASP.NET table "UsersInRoles" a additional Field called "`UIR_UserID [nvarchar(50)]`". What I want to do the trigger on insert is to get the UserId copied into to `UIR_UserId` field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_INS_DUPL_USER_ID] 
ON [dbo].[UsersInRoles] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO UsersInRoles(UIR_UserID)
SELECT UserId
FROM INSERTED
END
```

Comment: is there any specific reason why you need the same userid in another field UIR_userID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is no good and you'll get infinite recursion. I think you're looking to `UPDATE` the newly-inserted rows, not insert additional rows:

```
update u
set UIR_UserID = i.UserId
from dbo.UsersInRoles u
join inserted i on u.UserId = i.UserId
```

Alternatively, what it really looks like you're trying to do is abstract away the `UIR_UserID` field from the calling application. You could instead use a stored procedure or insertable view to perform this inline. Although the fact that you have duplicate data in two columns of the same row is still suspect either way.